# Auto adjust cell values if one cell values changed

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2007, excel-auto-fill

how to adjust values automatically if cell values A1 has changed means then the changed values has to adjusted with B2 values and the final cumulative values remains unchanged.

Suppose i have list of sales target for entire 12 months.
For January months if its 10 means and for February months it is 12 and the final cumulative is 120 for entire year.

Now if i changed the sales target for January month as 8 and it has to adjust the differenciated values (2) to next month's target as 12+2 = 14 and the final cumulative remains unchanged as 120.

Comment: So you want a row of values that must add up to a target value; and if one of the values is changed you want the values after it to adjust themselves automatically so they still add up to the target?

Comment: Yes werff! I making the sales target for the entire year and also month on month